# Is there any ros packge to find the orientation of face?

Tags: ros, kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get face position(x,y,z co-ordinates) using face_detector package.
is there anyway to get orientation as well.

I was getting face  position using stereo and Kinect cameras.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239351/is-there-any-ros-packge-to-find-the-orientation-of-face?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This package estimates the 6-DOF head pose with a monocular camera: https://github.com/chili-epfl/attention-tracker

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1